# Runtime exception(s) when running an F# benchmark on Mono

Tags: f#, mono, benchmarking

I am trying to compare the performance of a specific F# benchmark running on .NET and Mono 2.10.2 (Windows 7, 64-bit).  I took the [Spectral-Norm benchmark](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/program.php?test=spectralnorm&lang=fsharp&id=2#sourcecode) from the Benchmarks Game followed the traditional SO advice of using System.Diagnostics.StopWatch for benchmarking C# and added the lines 4, 89-90, and 93-95 at [this link](http://fssnip.net/5x).  I compiled this code in Visual Studio 2010 (For runtime 4.0, not client profile, any CPU, with optimize code and tail calls turned on).  The compiled code runs just fine on .NET (including inside VS), but when I run the .exe on Mono with "mono shootout_spectralnorm.exe" I get the following error (repeated in the fssnip.net link):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown
by the type initializer for System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch ---> System.InvalidPro
gramException: Invalid IL code in System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch:.cctor (): method
body is empty.

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Program.main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The strange thing is, when I remove the lines I had added (lines 4, 89-90, and 93-95, which relate to the timing part of the benchmark), the error goes away on Mono, and it acts just like it does on MS .NET.  This is just baffling me.  I set all of the referenced assemblies in VS to be copied locally, so they should be visible to Mono, but there could be some precedence issue with different assemblies in the GAC that have the same name as the ones in the local folder.  Has anyone encountered this issue or a similar one, especially on Windows Mono?  If so, or if you think you know how this problem could be fixed, I hope you can help me resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference Assemblies do not (often) have code - they are API signatures only (enough info for the compiler to reference them at design-time/compile-time).  You need to copy the runtime assemblies, not the reference assemblies, in order to run it.  (You'll often find the runtime assemblies in the GAC.)

Comment: So C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll is a runtime assembly, and the files VS copies into the directory are reference assemblies?

Comment: You are correct!  I was using the reference assemblies, and copying the runtime assemblies into the application's directory manually did the trick for Mono.  Now I just need to figure out why Mono takes 30 times longer on this benchmark...

Comment: @notostraca >>Now I just need to figure out why Mono takes 30 times longer on this benchmark.<< Somethings wrong with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260241/runtime-exceptions-when-running-an-f-benchmark-on-mono/6267814#6267814

Answer (score 0):

Here are measurements for FSharp-2.0.0.0 **spectral-norm #2** (Intel Q6600 quad-core, MS Vista 32 bit)

```
fsc     CPU s   Elapsed s
500     0.281   0.337
3000    4.883   1.453
5500    15.85   4.212

2.10.2  CPU s   Elapsed s
500     0.343   2.222
3000    4.836   3.361
5500    15.912  6.153

C:/Mono-2.10.2/bin/mono.exe C:/FSharp-2.0.0.0/bin/fsc.exe --platform:x86 
    --optimize+ --out:spectralnorm.exe spectralnorm.fsharpmono-2.fs

C:/Mono-2.10.2/bin/mono.exe --gc=sgen spectralnorm.exe 5500
```

[Now the benchmarks game spectral-norm on MS Vista demo, includes **F# on Mono**.](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/demo/performance.php?test=spectralnorm)